# How to add custom tab stops in Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

How can I apply these settings (especially "Default Spacing") programmatically to a docx created with Apache POI?

[image]

([image source](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH15339?locale=de_DE&viewlocale=en_US))

Currently I add tabs with

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun text = paragraph.createRun();
text.addTab();
```

but it looks just like a space until I manually adjust the spacing in Apple Pages...

EDIT: I googled a bit and extracted the content of my docx to compare it with what I want. It seems `text.addTab();` adds a ["Tab Character"](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_tab-2.html), while I am looking for a ([set](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_tabs-1.html) of) "[Custom Tab Stops](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_tab-1.html)".

Comment: After adding the tabs did you try auto-adjusting the columns programmatically?

Comment: Hm, this is about a word file, not an excel... or are there columns in word as well?

Comment: Doh. I thought question was about excel. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a few month ago, and I found proper solution to give "tab(\t)" space in '.XLSX' file.

Instead of  `cell.setCellValue("\t");`

you can give space like this

`cell.setCellValue("      ");` (just give multiple empty spaces...)

Comment: While I cannot verify your answer (I asked the question about 2 years ago after all) I'd guess your solution is purely cosmetic. I did not want to add multiple blank characters, I wanted to alter the space a tab character is using.